# Eclipse RCP export: missing dependencies in target platform

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I am trying to build existing RCP application against new target platform in order to get macosx(cocoa/aarch64). Using this update site: https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.23-I-builds.

The application works fine but when trying to export the RCP product with the wizard I get the following errors in the pde build log file:

```
Property "p2.director.log" has not been set
[p2.director] Installing com.client.product 5.1.0.
[p2.director] Installation failed.
[p2.director] Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
[p2.director]   Software being installed: PRODUCT 5.1.0 (com.client.product 5.1.0)
[p2.director]   Missing requirement: Equinox p2, headless functionalities 1.6.1300.v20220127-1112 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group 1.6.1300.v20220127-1112) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient5.feature.feature.group [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
[p2.director]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
[p2.director]       From: PRODUCT 5.1.0 (com.client.product 5.1.0)
[p2.director]       To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group [1.6.1300.v20220127-1112,1.6.1300.v20220127-1112]
[p2.director] Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
[p2.director] Software being installed: PRODUCT 5.1.0 (com.client.product 5.1.0)
[p2.director] Missing requirement: Equinox p2, headless functionalities 1.6.1300.v20220127-1112 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group 1.6.1300.v20220127-1112) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient5.feature.feature.group [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
[p2.director] Cannot satisfy dependency:
A problem occured while invoking the director.
runDirector:  duration 0 seconds
```

It appears that the following plugins can't be found:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; 
org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient5.feature.feature.group
```

What should I include in my target platform in order to resolve this?

Comment: The update site you use contains integration (I) builds of the upcoming and not yet released Eclipse project (platform+JDT) 4.23. [ECF](https://www.eclipse.org/ecf/) is a different project. Better use the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-12/`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-12/) or [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/) for your RCP application.

Comment: You don't need 4.23 for macOS aarch64, 2021-12 (4.22) is fine.

Comment: @greg-449 The 4.22 build has some issues with dependencies, this is why I looked at the version where these issues are resolved, see this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=577647 , this is why I was trying the development builds. Can anyone point out where these missing plugins come from?

Comment: @Dima `org.eclipse.ecf` → https://eclipse.org/ecf → Downloads. Does [`https://download.eclipse.org/rt/ecf/snapshot/site.p2/`](https://download.eclipse.org/rt/ecf/snapshot/site.p2/) work? Otherwise try [`https://download.eclipse.org/staging/2022-03`](https://download.eclipse.org/staging/2022-03) (latest snapshot build of the upcoming simultaneous release with ECF and other projects).

Comment: @howlger thank you for the answer, but no luck.. it doesn't work either with some other dependency errors.. I am giving up on this, will wait for the next release

Comment: OK, the release of Eclipse 2022-03 fixes the issues